# Values of all selectboxes in a form changes together

Tags: jquery

I have multiple fields in a form with drop downs . If I select one field value and click on other field's dropdown and select a value for that as well and now I change it using up/down arrow keys ... values of previous field even changes.I am guessing it to be a focus problem which might not be shifting but not sure .Can anybody tell me why is this happening and a possible solution for this?

Comment: _Can anybody tell me_, Sorry we can't read your code and thus can't help you.

Comment: Talk is cheap, show me your code ~ Linus Torvalds

Comment: Could you post your code, which could let us see what the real issue is